# GDB prints wrong values

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I've got a bit of a problem with debugging a C++ program using GDB.

When I use `print object.member`, it doesn't always print the value of the variable correctly. Instead, it prints the value of one of the arguments to the function I'm debugging. And it doesn't change through the function, although I change the value of `object.member` throughout.

And the thing is, the program is rather large and consists of several modules, with partially specialised templates and such, so I can't post it all here.
Now I tried to create a minimal testcase, but whatever simple I tried, I can't make it work. I mean, not work.

So all I can ask is, has anybody ever seen this behaviour in GDB, and have you found out what caused it and how to solve it?

There are question here about similar behaviour, but those amount to the program not being compiled properly (optimisation levels too high etc). I compiled it with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -O0`, so that can't be it.

And the program runs fine; I can `cout << object.member;` and that outputs the expected value, so I don't know what to try now.

Comment: What if you do `print object`? Do you have `set print pretty on`?

Comment: `p object` prints the same for `member`, and similar "random" values for the other members. I don't know how random it really is; I changed the program and the function several times now already, and still gdb's print insists that the member I'm after is identical to the first function parameter. It really feels like I'm missing something stupid.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this issue? If so, please post it here.

Comment: @nimrodm Nope, no answers yet. (By now, the program works correctly, so I haven't had any need to use GDB with it any more and it's no longer an urgent issue.) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behaviour before. Unfortunately, gdb is really 'C' based so although it will deal with C++, I've found it occasionally to be quite picky about displaying values.

When displaying more complex items (such as maps, strings or the dereferenced contents of smart pointers) you have to sometimes be quite explicit about dereferencing and casting variables.

Another possibility is the function itself - anything unusual about it? Is it templated for example?

Can you create a reference to this variable in your code and try displaying that? Or take the address of the variable and derefrence the contents - only if it's publicly available of course.

Naturally the source code **must** match what you've compiled so must be older than the exe but gdb will normally warn you about such things

Comment: Hm. Yes, I was afraid that it might be a matter of C++ incompatibility. But I made a SSCCE with the same properties (or so I hoped), an instance of a partially specialised templated class, and that worked flawlessly with GDB. So I'm not sure what to try now. I changed it so the name of the variable was unique to the whole application. I tried `p (const char*)name.member` in gdb. And yes, I did make clean and make before running gdb. But all that didn't change a thing.

Comment: I can change the function though. It's not templated, but it is a static class member. A little experimentation won't hurt. Stand by.

Comment: Oh boy. So I have `encstr result; encstr& resultref = result;` in my source now, and when I do `p result` in gdb, I get the random output, but when I do `p resultref` the output is correct. Why?