# gdb unexpected behavior: in nested if

Tags: c, gdb

I am using

```
    p12user@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
    Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-40-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 6 00:56:56 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    p12user@ubuntu:~$ gdb -v
    GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1-ubuntu
    Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.

    p12user@ubuntu:~/programming$ gcc --version
    gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
    Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
    warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

On debugging this program in gdb, which is compiled as `gcc -g program.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int condition1 = 1;
   if(condition1)
   {
      if(!condition1)
      {
         printf("The control shouldn't come here.\n");
      }
   }
   else
   {
      printf("in else\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

the behaviour is:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at program.c:4
4               int condition1 = 1;
(gdb) n
5               if(condition1)
(gdb) n
7                       if(!condition1)
(gdb) n
9                               printf("The control shouldn't come here.\n");
(gdb) n
16              return 0;
(gdb) n
17      }
(gdb)
```

The behaviour at LINE 9 is unexpected in gdb. However, the print statement is only shown in gdb but not executed. And if I put a matching ELSE (with some print statement) with inner-IF then this doesn't happen, also if matching ELSE for outer-IF is removed then this doesn't happen. Am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't changed the source between you started gdb and running? Gdb reads the source from file, and if it's been changed it will show the source wrong.

Comment: I do know that GDB can produce unexpected results. I had [a question about GDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315430/gdb-prints-wrong-values) too. No idea how reliable it is on the whole.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're building your program *without* any kinds of optimization, as the program you've shown seems to be trivially optimizable which can lead to source code statements not making into the executable.

In GCC you'd use:

```
gcc -O0 ...
```

or

```
g++ -O0 ...
```

for this.

Comment: added the relevant switch as the output of the OP looks like it's GCC.

Comment: I used command `gcc -g -O0 -fno-inline program.c` to compile, and I tried it on some other machine also. But it still showed the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

in

```
2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
GNU gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5)
```

it is ok!