# is it a gdb bug?

Tags: c++, string, gdb

```
 1 #include "string"
 2 using namespace std;
 3 
 4 bool m_bInited = true;
 5 int  m_imaxsize = 100;
 6 
 7 int test()
 8 {
 9     if (!m_bInited)
10     {
11         return -1;
12     }
13 
14     std::string gbkInput = "";
15     std::string utf8Input = "";
16     if (gbkInput.size() > m_imaxsize)
17     {
18         return 1;
19     }
20     return 0;
21 }
22 
23 int main()
24 {
25     test();
26     return 0;
27 }
```

when using gdb step from line 16, the debug sequence is:

line 16 -> line 20 -> line 18 -> line 21.

```
    (gdb) b 16
    (gdb) r
    Breakpoint 1, test () at main.cpp:16
    16          if (gbkInput.size() > m_imaxsize)
    (gdb) n
    20          return 0;
    (gdb) n
    18              return 1;
    (gdb) n
    21      }
```

compile: g++ -g main.cpp -o test

why gdb display line 18 ?   and the test() return value is 0.

my gcc version is 4.1.2. 
GNU gdb Fedora (6.8-37.el5)  or  GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.0.1-37.el5)  . 
Both gdb version has this problem.

BTW: if move line 14,line 15 (these 2 string var) to line 9, it will be ok.  gdb will not display line 18 !
it seemed the string var cause this bug.

Can everyone help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Note that gdb can only make use of the debugging information it has in the binary, so when instructions at 0x1,0x2,0x3 have in their debug information "0x01 == line 34, 0x02 == line 33, 0x03 == line31" then gdb can't display anything else. Use addr2line to see what is in there if you are curious.

Comment: Line 16 as posted in your code and the gdb trace you've provided are different. Did you post the actual code?

Comment: BTW, it should be `#include <string>`, not `#include "string"`.

Comment: Could it be - since the source differs as dirkgently pointed out - that the compiler invocation differs, too? Could it be that you ran the compiler with optimization enabled? That usually results in just that kind of "jumping" you describe.

Comment: to  dirkgently, I edit the gdb trace. :-). The result not changed !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow isn't the same as most web forums: if you have more information to add to your question, please use the edit link in your original question. Don't post it as an Answer; you should only post an Answer if you've actually found an answer to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @DevSolar, my gcc configure:Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is a "feature" of older versions of gcc/gdb, and it's been reported here before: [gdb unexpected behavior: in nested if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701700/gdb-unexpected-behavior-in-nested-if). Note: This question can't be marked as a duplicate of that other as there was no satisfactory solution.

The statement isn't being executed. It just looks like it.

**Addendum**
It's easy to verify that the statement is not being executed. Add a function

```
int one() {
   return 1;
}
```

Then replace that `return 1;` with `return one();` gdb will print `return one();` but it does not call the function `one()`. Apparently there's a problem in older versions of gdb with displaying the execution of the close brace on an if statement.

Note well: This only happens with older versions of gdb, and it's apparently a problem of display rather than of incorrect program execution.

Comment: Could not reproduce this on GDB SUSE 7.1-8.9.1 and GCC 4.1.2, which isn't really "recent"...

Comment: I reproduced it with gcc 4.2.1 and gdb 6.3.50. Behavior was exactly that described by the OP. Note that the OP is using gcc 4.1.2 and gdb 6.8 or gdb 7.0.1. No, those aren't "recent". They are quite common however because of gnu's switch to GPL version 3 after gcc 4.1.2 / gcc 4.2.1.

Comment: to David Hammen, i had read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701700/gdb-unexpected-behavior-in-nested-if, but not

Comment: @fdffdf : but not -- what? See my addendum to my answer.

Comment: @DavidHammen you mean: int one() {return one(); }  ?

Comment: reproduce it with GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4 , gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46) .