# When would a debugger lie?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

So, after a week of dealing with a really voodoo bug (which was solved, but of course, by adding one `#include` in a relevant place) I realized that one shouldn't always trust the debugger and if something doesn't make sense, good old `printf()`may be of use to you. 
From what I knew a debugger might "lie" if the code is being compiled in release mode. I recently learnt that if a class has an `#ifdef`, something like

```
struct MyStruct
{
    char a;
#ifdef USE_ME
    double c;
#else
    int c;
#endif
};
```

and the `USE_ME` is not defined in a header visible to the struct definition, but is defined elsewhere, than the debugger gets confused because it doesn't know what type c is and will "lie", even if we are in debug mode. 
My question is: Can anyone give other situations as to when a debugger would lie?

Comment: Which debugger on which platform? This doesn't happen with most Windows debuggers because they work from the PDB not the source code.

Comment: How did this even compile then, in the first place?  You might want to consider using the highest level of compiler warnings, and treat warnings as errors.

Comment: @Ben: source-level debugging on optimized binaries is really imprecise even with PDBs, since the optimized code often is difficult to correlate with particular lines of the original sources.

Comment: It's C++ - why do you use some weird preprocessor magic instead of templates?

Comment: @Chris O - it compiled.. and since I am working on a project which consists of over 2M LOC and includes about 15 years of legacy, using the highest level of compiler warnings (or even looking at warnings I must admit) is not something we usually do. However, I did go read through the ~1000 warnings and didn't see anything significant.

Comment: I've had GDB tell me lies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315430/gdb-prints-wrong-values

Comment: Are you sure your debug build has NO optimizations turned on?  Many compilers have half-a-dozen options which affect optimization and if you don't have them *all* turned off in the debug build, you can end up with things reordered or optimized away.  While it could be a compiler bug, it's been my experience that 99.9% of the time when I think it's a compiler bug, the error is in my code.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, In optimised code a single instruction could correspond to more than one source line (e.g. comdat folding). A single memory location could correspond to more than one variable (e.g. if the space is reused). But the debugger will never be confused by an #if line.

Comment: Its important to keep in mind that debuggers never lie. They just show you what things really look like which in release may not be what you expect.

Comment: @Ben: I was referring exactly to that kind of problems. But when distinguishing between different versions of the same structure they can be naive (as many non-compiler tools that work on C++ code they may be fooled easily by the precompiler & co.)

Answer (score 4):

The debugger generally doesn't lie (unless it's buggy). It tells you exactly what's going on in your program. Your problem is that what goes on in your program is different from what you *thought* was going on in your program -- or different from what you wrote in your source code.

When the compiler optimizes your code (for example when you're building a release build), it transforms the code in a number of ways, meaning that operations will be reordered or removed entirely.

When you debug, the debugger tries its best to correlate what's going on with what's written in the source code, but it can't do so perfectly, simply because the compiler may have chosen completely different ways to achieve the same goals. So you'll often see that variables either can't be seen at all in the debugger (they've been optimized out), or they have unexpected values, or you'll see the debugger jump seemingly randomly between different source code lines.

So the debugger doesn't lie. It just tells you a different truth than you expected to see. It tells you the truth of what's actually happening in your program -- and not the "truth" of what was written in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

A typical example of lies occurs with memory corruption (either stack or heap corruption), and in general memory-related issues (dangling references for example).

This is one consequence of invoking **undefined behavior**, even the behavior of the debugger is undefined in this case because the debugger is working from the compiled code which is not valid.

Debuggers are good at helping with logical issues in otherwise well-formed programs, and can help spot some errors (null dereferencing for example) in ill-formed programs; but not all classes of ill-formed programs can be efficiently debugged. And of course things get even hairier in multi-threaded programs (among others), since the very fact of observing the program changes its behavior...

Answer (score 0):

The debugger can lie in two scenarios:

1. You are debugging with missing/incorrect symbols (including your symbols and the OS's symbols).
2. You have a bad build.  Maybe some stale .OBJs got linked, without first being rebuilt instead.  This can sometimes happen on large projects/solutions, especially if you are using "old fashioned" ways of specifying project dependencies instead of the official way with VS2010.