# Why is GDB printed address different from cerr printed address?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I'm trying to debug with GDB, but there's a very strange thing occurring. When I print `std::cerr << current_node << std::endl;` I get the an address `0x7a1ad0`. However, when I go into GDB and enter the command `print current_node`, I receive the address `0x46863f`. As I'm trying to debug something which is happening inside `current_node`, this is proving to be a problem. (Note: both the `cerr` and GDB `print` statements are run within the same instance of GDB)

I realize that this isn't a very good example, and probably can't be replicated, but I was wondering if maybe I anyone had any idea what could cause this to happen inside GDB. In any case, I'm currently debugging the code by instrumenting it with `cerr` statements everywhere instead of using GDB.

Comment: `0x46863f` is almost certainly not a valid address.

Comment: What's the type of `current_node`?

Comment: It's a user created `GraphNode*` object. Also, I just found a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315430/gdb-prints-wrong-values

Although, that questions also doesn't seem to have an accepted answer.

Comment: You usually should not use raw pointers in C++. Why don't you use STL containers?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm using a raw pointer because I haven't learned how to use anything else, and the framework I'm working in does the same, so I thought I would mimic them for consistency. I'll look up STL containers and see if this helps.

Comment: What options are you building your program with?  Specifically, are you specifying `-O0`?

Comment: BTW, you should learn more about about [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and about `gdb`. Its `watch` command is very powerful to debug such things. Don't forget to disable [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) in your system to have a repeatable behavior.

Comment: Does the class `GraphNode` inherit multiple parent classes? What does `whatis current_node` say in gdb?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I'm sorry to say that I don't know. I'm using a premade makefile that was provided to me. I don't really know how to navigate this makefile either.

Comment: @urzeit It doesn't inherit any classes. `whatis current_node` prints `type = CR::GraphNode *`, where CR is the namespace all my specific files are inside.

Comment: Does the build process log the compiler commands it's running (even to the console)?  Can you `grep -- "-O" Makefile` (or whatever your make file is)?  There's probably a `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` variable defined in the make file that specifies the optimization flag. Note that for GCC, a plain `-O` flag  is equivalent to `-O1` which enables basic optimizations. You should have `-O0` specified when compiling for debugging.

Comment: @MichaelBurr There is no `-O` inside the makefile. Is it possible to define variables in one makefile, and reference it in another? If so, I may have to check some of the other files, but the main one I call has no `-O`. The makefile doesn't log the compiler commands, but instead only echoes what is being compiled.

Comment: Having no `-O` option in the makefile should be equivalent to no optimizations.  I'd still try to specify it explicitly using something like `make CFLAGS=-O0` or `make CXXFLAGS=-O0`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr It appears that doing so (`make CXXFLAGS=-O0`) doesn't allow it to compile anymore, somehow causing it to be unable to find various `.h` files. Again, sorry I'm not very helpful here. I'm only just learning how makefiles work, and this is my first large(ish) project.

Comment: It sounds like your makefile depends on `CXXFLAGS` being set with some values in your environment.  Try running the following command before running `make` in your usual way: `export CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS -O0`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70620/discussion-between-teofrostus-and-michael-burr).